# I don't have the whole project from git

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, github

I am new to git. I made a repo and added a friend of mine to also contribute. He pushes the changes. Then i pull them and when i open solution explorer in vs 2015 it shows up only the files he was working on, but not mine. I searched in the file explorer and my files ARE there. How to view them from vs?

Comment: Are you in the same `branch`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that you simply don't have your files included in the appropriate *.csproj file for your project. This actually sometimes happens to me as well. If you just right-click on the appropriate parent folder(s) in VS and select "add existing", that usually is all you need to do.

Post back if that doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks a LOT for the fast answer. I do not find a add existing. Just exactly under the Solution Explorer there is a button "show all files". When i click it i see the missing files but they are ...... Nevermind I found it. Oh, god. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @MitkoRusev if this response helped you to solve your problem please mark it as the accepted answer :)